# How to use Angular ngFor with Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, ngfor

With `Book` class defined as:

```
class Book {
   id: number;
   name: string;
   constructor(id: number, name: string) { 
     this.id = id;
     this.name = name;
  }
}
```

I go ahead and create `Observable` object `books$`:

```
const book1: Book = new Book(1, "Title 1");
const book2: Book = new Book(2, "Title 2");
function booklist(observer) {
  observer.next(book1);
  observer.next(book2);
  observer.complete();
  return {unsubscribe() {}};
}
this.books$ = new Observable(booklist);
```

Checking it with:

```
this.books$.subscribe(each => console.log(each));
```

prints:

```
Book {id: 1, name: "Title 1"}
Book {id: 2, name: "Title 2"}
```

But using this observable with `ngFor` in the html template:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let book of books$ | async" >
    Id: {{book.id}}, Name: {{book.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

raises the `ERROR`:

```
   Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'Title 2'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

How to solve this problem? Here is the link to [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-isebs7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) project:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-isebs7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks good except `books$` represent a stream of objects, not arrays. So might have to use [`keyvalue`](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe. Try the following

```html
<ul>
  <ng-container *ngIf="(books$ | async) as books">
    <li *ngFor="let book of books | keyvalue" >
      {{book.key}}: {{book.value}}
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

#### Update: RxJS `bufferCount` operator

The above solution however prints only the current notification. If you wish to collect each notification and display them all, you could use RxJS [`bufferCount`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/bufferCount) (or [`buffer`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/buffer) if you don't exactly the amount of notifications) operator to collect all the notifications.

Controller

```js
import { bufferCount } from 'rxjs/operators';  

ngOnInit(): void {
  ...
  this.books$ = <Observable<Book[]>>(new Observable(booklist).pipe(bufferCount(2)));
  this.books$.subscribe(each => console.log(each));
}
```

Template

```html
<ul>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let books of books$ | async">
    <li *ngFor="let book of books | keyvalue" >
      {{book.key}}: {{book.value}}
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eszacf)

Comment: you emit object by object. That's the problem. As indicated by @Michael D, it is not an array but stream of objects.

Comment: May be the solution would be to represent `books$` as an `Iterable` array? The `HttpClient.get(url)` method always returns the iterable observable the `ngFor` works fine with..

Comment: Yes. `ngFor` must have `Iterable array`. Angular complains about it in your example too.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ywtfze?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts check it.

Comment: Can we add an `iterator` to the `books$` observable?

Comment: `observer.next([book1, book2]);` works like a charm! Highly appreciated!

Comment: @alphanumeric: You could return an `iterable` to loop over it. As a quick shortcut, you could also use RxJS `buffer` operators to collect the notifications. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would extract this behaviour into a new method:

```
getBooksArr$: Observable<Book[]> {
   return this.books$.pipe(map((book) => Object.values(book)));
}
```

In the html:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let book of getBooksArr$() | async" >
    Id: {{book.id}}, Name: {{book.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```